# Observable.forkJoin call delayed after return of function

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

In component we are subscribing the two http return result from a service and in service the two http calls are returning observerable.

In component typscript

```
catalogPromise = this.ondemandService.getVodCatalog().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);

        });
```

In Service :-

```
    getVodCatalog(url,user){
    return this.getVodCategories().map((data) => {
            let result,result2;
            let Observers = [],
            cats = [],
            catalogs = [];

            result=data.json();
            result.categorylist.forEach((catergory) => {
                cats.push(catergory.name);
                Observers.push(this.getCategoriesCatolog(catergory.id,{}));
            });
            console.log(Observers);
            Observable.forkJoin(Observers).subscribe((vodCatalogs)=> {
                vodCatalogs.forEach((vodeCatalog,idx)=>{
                    let v1 = vodeCatalog.json();
                    if(v1.vodlist)
                    {
                        catalogs.push({
                            label: cats[idx],
                            list: v1.vodlist
                            });
                    }
                });
                return catalogs;
            });

        })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}


    getVodCategories(){
        let url="http://CategoryList";
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type':     'application/json','Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*'});
        let body = {
                offset: 0,
                count: -1,
                type: 'dfasd',
                categoryid: -1,
             };
        let options = new RequestOptions({
             headers: headers,
             url:url,
             withCredentials: true,
             timeout:30000,
             body:body
         });
         return this._http.post(url,body,options);
     }

     getCategoriesCatolog(cateogoryId,options){
         var url="http://VodList";
         let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type':    'application/json','Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*' });
         let body = {
                  count: 100,
                  offset: 0,
                  orderType: 0,
                  categoryid: cateogoryId,
            };
            options = new RequestOptions({
             url:url,
             withCredentials: true,
             timeout:30000,
             body:body
         });
        return this._http.post(url,body,options);
    }
```

In service, getVodCategories() and getCategoriesCatolog() are returning observable result but when we are trying to subscribe it in the component, whole data is being undefined and after that Observable.forkjoin() is running.

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid nested observable , use merge insteda like below

```
Rx.Observable.merge(
  myService.upload('upload1'),
  myService.upload('upload2')
.take(2)
.subscribe({complete: () => { ... });
```

Comment: The problem is   result.categorylist.forEach((catergory) => {
                cats.push(catergory.name);
                Observers.push(this.getCategoriesCatolog(catergory.id,{}));
            });

Comment: The problem is        result.categorylist.forEach((catergory) => {
                cats.push(catergory.name);
                Observers.push(this.getCategoriesCatolog(catergory.id,{}));
            });

When we make a call to getCategoriesCatalog, it takes down a parameter of cat id  which comes from catelogylist, Array of Observable come and Observables contains different response which we have to return in the component data.but after using merge i am not able to subscribe the required result. The first call result should be used in the second call parameter. This is problem please rply

Comment: Return promise from service and catch it in component. In service you can have all your subscribe.